# content only appears on page when I've clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have connected by Angular 2 application to Firebase 3 nothing to outrageous, just a simple table which contains a small set of data.

Inside my angular 2 application I have created service inside the service I have created a listener event as shown here:

```
getAddedBugs(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
        this.bugsDbRef.on('child_added', bug => {
            const newBug = bug.val() as Bug;                                            
            obs.next(newBug);
        },
        err => {
            obs.throw(err)
        });
    });
}
```

I inject this service into my bug.component.ts and call the given function specified above :

```
 getAddedBugs() {
    this.bugService.getAddedBugs().subscribe(bug => {
        this.bugs.push(bug);
    },
        err => {
            console.error("unable to get added bug - ", err);
        });
}
```

this populates an array, which I'm then able to loop over within the HTML and build the table content as shown here:

```
 <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let bug of bugs">
      <td>{{ bug.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ bug.status }}</td>
      <td>{{ bug.severity }}</td>
      <td>{{ bug.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ bug.createdBy }}</td>
      <td>{{ bug.createdDate }}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

The issue I have is when I load the page I see nothing on the page, however when I click on the page, i.e the table headers for example then table content within the `*ngFor` then appears? and no I don't have anything wired up for the headers so I'm not calling any additional functions.

Can someone explain to me why I have to click the page to see the table content appear?

Comment: The issue is change detection , what is this.bugsDbRef.on ? is it inside the angular2 code ?

Comment: @Milad bugsDbRef is my firebase database connection: `private bugsDbRef = this.firebase.database.ref('/bugs');`

Comment: Alright , and what is your component changeDetectionStrategy ?

Comment: @Milad it doesn't have a changeDetectionStrategy as of yet, I'm just trying to get everything to appear on page load. `getAddedBugs` is called from within `ngOnInit()`

Answer (score 1):

I assume your problem is that `this.bugsDbRef.on` is not inside the Angular2 zone, so when it get's it's values and updates the model, Angular doesn't know about it, and when you click , the change detection fires up and detects the Component changes and updates the view accordingly.

You probably need to do one of this :

Run the push inside the zone :

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone){}

this.zone.run(()=>{
   this.bugs.push(bug);
})
```

Or

Run the detectChanges after the push

```
   constructor(private cd:ChangeDetectorRef){}
   this.bugs.push(bug);
   this.cd.detectChanges();
```

Or

Run it inside a setTimeout

```
   setTimeout(()=>{
       this.bugs.push(bug);
   });
```

And by the way, you can make it more clear by using async pipe :

```
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let bug of bugs | async">
      <td>{{ bug.title }}</td>
      <td>{{ bug.status }}</td>
      <td>{{ bug.severity }}</td>
      <td>{{ bug.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ bug.createdBy }}</td>
      <td>{{ bug.createdDate }}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

and your service :

```
getAddedBugs() {
    this.bugService.getAddedBugs(); // remove the subscribe
}
```