# Component data takes 18 seconds to display on page

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an angular 2 application, I have a simple page that consists of a HTML table, inside the component for the HTML page I call a service which connects to Firebase 3 and retrieves the values from the given table, the table looks like this:

[image]

My bug.componenet.ts looks like this:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BugService } from '../service/bug.service';
import { Bug } from '../model/bug';


@Component({
   selector: 'bug-list',
   templateUrl: './bug-list.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./bug-list.component.css']
})

export class BugListComponent implements OnInit {

   private bugs: Bug[] = [];

   constructor(private bugService: BugService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.getAddedBugs();
   }


   getAddedBugs() {
        this.bugService.getAddedBugs().subscribe(bug => {
          this.bugs.push(bug);
        },
        err => {
            console.error("unable to get added bug - ", err);
        });
     }

  }
```

The BugService:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

//Observables
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

// Services
import { FirebaseConfigService } from '../../core/service/firebase-config.service';

// Models
import { Bug } from '../model/bug';


@Injectable()
export class BugService {

// being my firebase database connection.
private bugsDbRef = this.fire.database.ref('/bugs');

constructor(private fire: FirebaseConfigService) { 

    console.log(this.bugsDbRef);

}

getAddedBugs(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(obs => {
        this.bugsDbRef.on('child_added', bug => {
            const newBug = bug.val() as Bug;         
            console.log(newBug);
            obs.next(newBug);
        },
        err => {
            obs.throw(err)
        });
    });
}
}
```

And now for the bug.html page:

```ts
 <tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let bug of bugs">
     <td>{{ bug.title }}</td>
     <td>{{ bug.status }}</td>
     <td>{{ bug.severity }}</td>
     <td>{{ bug.description }}</td>
     <td>{{ bug.createdBy }}</td>
     <td>{{ bug.createdDate }}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Which renders :

[image]

The issue I have is when I load the page, I have to wait at least 18 seconds before the bugs from firebase are displayed in the table for some reason... however inside the service when I `console.log(newBug);` they appear immediately.

Can someone shed any light into what might be causing this issue?

Thanks

** Update **

This is my firebase cofiguration file which is referenced from within the bug.service.ts

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';
require('firebase/database');

// Constants
import { FIREBASE_CONFIG } from '../constant/constants';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseConfigService {

private _database: firebase.database.Database;

constructor() {
    this.configureApp();
    this.configureDatabase();
}

public get database(){
    return this._database;
}

configureApp() {
    firebase.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);
}

configureDatabase() {

    this._database = firebase.database();


}

}
```

I inject the above into the bug.service constructor.

Comment: @CodeRathet : 
Why did you ask this question again and why didn't you use the answer I wrote for you and  why didn't you accept it there and why would you waste people's time ? ( Thanks in advance ).

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372570/content-only-appears-on-page-when-ive-clicked/41372658#41372658

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be change detection not being run.

I guess you're initializing the Firebase library outside Angular which makes the code run outside Angulars zone, which causes Angular not recognizing async calls being completed, which causes Angular not to run change detection and therefore doesn't update the DOM.

Either ensure Firebase is initialized inside Angular or invoke change detection explicitely

```ts
constructor(private bugService: BugService, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) { }

getAddedBugs() {
    this.bugService.getAddedBugs().subscribe(bug => {
      this.bugs.push(bug);
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    },
```

Comment: Hey they seemed to of worked using the ChangeDetectorRef, when you say ensure firebase is initialized inside Angular how would I go about doing that? because I was under the impression it was running within Angular 2?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I haven't used Firebase myself. But usually code initialized within Angular causes change detection to happen when an async call was completed. Where and how do you initialize Firebase? Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: Just added the firebase configuration file, which is injected into the bug service, I then refer to the `public get database()` within the bug service. Which returns me the firebase database connection.

Comment: No way for me to know what firebase-config.service is doing. Do you use https://github.com/angular/angularfire2?

Comment: The `firebase-config.service` is basically configuring the firebase connection, this file in particular gets injected into the bug.service. I looked an AngularFire2 however had an issues getting it setup, so instead just reverted back to npm install firebase

Comment: Then the firebase library you're using is probably using an API that is not covered by Angulars zone. Then you need to use `detectChanges()`.

Comment: That's probably why then, shame but never mind.  I will take a look at AngularFire2 and also read up on the Angular Zones as I feel that would be beneficial to my learning.  Thanks for your help, have a good day / evening.